# Can I submit MVC6 view component?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-viewcomponent

Can I submit form inside view component somehow? I know it is not possible for partial views. View component has its own controller, so the goal of this question is if I can use this controller for submitting form rendered by component view.

It is not mentioned in [MVC6 view components docs](http://docs.asp.net/projects/mvc/en/latest/views/view-components.html).
So it is not possible, I guess, but maybe I'm wrong :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Similar to partial views, view components can also render you some HTML. So as long as the view rendered by your view component has a valid form tag in it, Yes, you can submit forms.

```
@model YourNamespace.LoginVM
<form asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Login">
    <input asp-for="Name" />
    <input asp-for="Password" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

You need to make sure that you have a Login action method in HomeController

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Login(LoginVM model)
{
   //do something :)
}
```

The important thing to remember is, You should not be calling this view component inside another form tag. The general rule is, **you should not be nesting forms**.

```
<form id="main-form" asp-controller="main" asp-action="submit" method="post">
    <input asp-for="LocationName" />
    <input type="submit"  />
</form>

@Component.Invoke("Login")
```

Comment: Im pretty sure you can't post data using component.invoke

Comment: As long as you have a form in it, you can submit it. View components are nothing part a helper to render a chunk of markup in your page(similar to partial views).

Comment: Would there be a difference between submitting a form via Component.Invoke then making an Ajax call?  I see partial views as the server serving a static content, while Viewcomponents call the server to serve dynamic content (much like an ajax call returning dynamic content without returning a whole new view).  Is this correct??

Comment: View components executes in server

Comment: so if i needed to submit a form when would it be better to use a Ajax call vs a ViewComponents?